# If $A \ge B$ then $A[α] \ge B[α]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in  M_n$ be Hermitian. If $A \ge B$ and

$α ⊂ {\rm{\{ 1, }}{\rm{. }}{\rm{. }}{\rm{. , n\} }}$.

Why does $A[α] \ge B[α]$ ?

(Note: $A[α]$ is submatrix of $A$ )

Comment: Hint: $<x,Ax>=<x[\alpha],A[\alpha]x[\alpha]>$

Comment: @Surb Do you know about the two commands `\langle \rangle`? They give the brackets you really want: $\langle x, Ax\rangle$.

Comment: @Surb also, your statement is not quite true without further assumptions on $x$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Indeed, my idea was to say, let $y$ then $<y,A[\alpha]y> = <x,Ax>$ where $x$ is the vector $y$ to which we add zero entries to make the dimension correct.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I know these commands. I think they are not worth the effort for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\geqslant B$, $A-B$ is positive semi-definite. So all its principal minors are nonnegative and positive semi-definite, i.e. $(A-B)[\alpha]\geqslant 0$, which means that $A[\alpha]\geqslant B[\alpha]$.